# Airflow DB initialization on WSL

Tags: python, airflow, windows-subsystem-for-linux

i'am trying to install Airflow on WSL by following tutorial - https://medium.com/international-school-of-ai-data-science/setting-up-apache-airflow-in-windows-using-wsl-dbb910c04ae0
When i've reached `airflow db init` step, i've started to get error message like this:

```
DB: sqlite:////mnt/c/Users/baron/Documents/airflow/airflow.db
/home/darius/airflow_env/lib/python3.10/site-packages/pydantic/_internal/_config.py:257 UserWarning: Valid config keys have changed in V2:
* 'orm_mode' has been renamed to 'from_attributes'
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/darius/airflow_env/bin/airflow", line 8, in <module>
    sys.exit(main())
  File "/home/darius/airflow_env/lib/python3.10/site-packages/airflow/__main__.py", line 48, in main
    args.func(args)
  File "/home/darius/airflow_env/lib/python3.10/site-packages/airflow/cli/cli_config.py", line 52, in command
    return func(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/home/darius/airflow_env/lib/python3.10/site-packages/airflow/cli/commands/db_command.py", line 37, in initdb
    db.initdb()
  File "/home/darius/airflow_env/lib/python3.10/site-packages/airflow/utils/session.py", line 76, in wrapper
    return func(*args, session=session, **kwargs)
  File "/home/darius/airflow_env/lib/python3.10/site-packages/airflow/utils/db.py", line 711, in initdb
    import_all_models()
  File "/home/darius/airflow_env/lib/python3.10/site-packages/airflow/models/__init__.py", line 60, in import_all_models    __getattr__(name)
  File "/home/darius/airflow_env/lib/python3.10/site-packages/airflow/models/__init__.py", line 78, in __getattr__
    val = import_string(f"{path}.{name}")`
  `File "/home/darius/airflow_env/lib/python3.10/site-packages/airflow/utils/module_loading.py", line 36, in import_string
    module = import_module(module_path)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.10/importlib/__init__.py", line 126, in import_module
    return _bootstrap._gcd_import(name[level:], package, level)
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1050, in _gcd_import
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1027, in _find_and_load
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1006, in _find_and_load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 688, in _load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap_external>", line 883, in exec_module
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 241, in _call_with_frames_removed
  File "/home/darius/airflow_env/lib/python3.10/site-packages/airflow/models/skipmixin.py", line 25, in <module>
    from airflow.serialization.pydantic.dag_run import DagRunPydantic
  File "/home/darius/airflow_env/lib/python3.10/site-packages/airflow/serialization/pydantic/dag_run.py", line 24, in <module>
    from airflow.serialization.pydantic.dataset import DatasetEventPydantic
  File "/home/darius/airflow_env/lib/python3.10/site-packages/airflow/serialization/pydantic/dataset.py", line 40, in <module>
    class TaskOutletDatasetReferencePydantic(BaseModelPydantic):
  File "/home/darius/airflow_env/lib/python3.10/site-packages/pydantic/_internal/_model_construction.py", line 95, in __new__
    private_attributes = inspect_namespace(
  File "/home/darius/airflow_env/lib/python3.10/site-packages/pydantic/_internal/_model_construction.py", line 328, in inspect_namespace
    raise PydanticUserError(
pydantic.errors.PydanticUserError: A non-annotated attribute was detected: `task_id = <class 'str'>`. All model fields require a type annotation; if `task_id` is not meant to be a field, you may be able to resolve this error by annotating it as a `ClassVar` or updating `model_config['ignored_types'].
```

Can anyone help me with this error solution ? First time seeing it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

please add in `requirements.txt`

```
pydantic==1.10.10
```

https://www.reddit.com/r/apache_airflow/comments/14oji77/airflow_262_and_pydantic_warningserrors/

Answer (score 0):

When I installed airflow 2.6.2 on my Mac and attempted to create the database I got a similar error:

site-packages/pydantic/_internal/_config.py:261 UserWarning: Valid config keys have changed in V2:* 'orm_mode' has been renamed to 'from_attributes'

Apparently it installed pydantic 2.0.2.

pip install pydantic==1.10.0 (as mentioned by seunggabi) fixed my problem.